# My Rigging animations looks different in FBX import than in .blend

Tags: animation, rigging, export, import, .fbx

When I'm animating this FPS game I'm making, the original .blend file looks fine and the way it was supposed. Here is a pic:
[image]

But here is what happens when I import the FBX file into blender:

[image]

The bones in the import work, but the left arm is not moving along with it. Here is what I import with it:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your armature in pose position or rest position when you export it? If your unsure check in the armature tab in the properties window.

Comment: It is in pose position when I export it. The weird thing is, when I import it, the right hand animation does what it is supposed to, but the left hand stands completely still

Comment: Perhaps you need to set weight-paint quality in Unity?
https://forum.unity.com/threads/blender-fbx-to-unity-weight-painting-problem.733301/

Comment: Do you know why the left handed vertex groups disappear on the import? I just noticed this detail.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. Perhaps those vertex groups have weight-paints assigned, but the right ones do not.